# Intellisense syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Does there exist a means of getting syntax highlighting/colouring happening in Intellisense pop-ups? 
Call me a newbie, but it takes me forever to find the space between type and member in something like this:

[image: Iterator for vector holding boost filesystem paths]

Let alone this:

[image]

I know productivity power tools has this for C# function parameter popups, but I'd like this in C++ for all member types.

Comment: VS doesn't support that natively (that I know of), but if  you're willing to buy a tool, Visual Assist X will do it. (I have no affiliation with them)